# open WCF svc file error in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, iis

I am using VS2010 + C# + .Net 4.0 + IIS 7.5 + Windows 7. When I open a WCF svc file in IIS 7.0, there is some error like this, any ideas what is wrong?

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'foo.test' or one of its dependencies.

Comment: If this is a 64 bit OS maybe your assembly is compiled to target `x86` instead of `Any CPU` and IIS doesn't authorize 32 bit code to run.

Comment: I build for anycpu and the machine is 64-bit. Anything wrong? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the application pool is configured to target CLR 2.0. You need to change it to target .NET 4.0:

[image]

Also make sure .NET 4.0 is registered by running:

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Comment: It is configured to 4.0. Any ideas to find more information, like which dependent assembly is looking for?

Comment: Does this `foo.test` assembly mentioned in the exception have any other dependencies? Does it run unmanaged code?

Comment: For aspnet_regiis, I think it registers ASP.Net to IIS, not .Net 4.0?

Comment: No it registers .NET 4.0 with IIS because you are running it from the v4.0.30319 folder.

Comment: "Does this foo.test assembly mentioned in the exception have any other dependencies? Does it run unmanaged code?" -- yes, it has some dependencies, but all are managed code. I have just tried the same process on a 32-bit machine, no issues. Anything wrong?

Comment: "No it registers .NET 4.0 with IIS because you are running it from the v4.0.30319 folder" -- if I can see .Net 4.0 can be selected from IIS worker process pool, it means .Net 4.0 has already registered correct?

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Had the same problem. I was getting 404 errors instead of `BadImageFormatException` until I ran this command even if I was seeing .NET 4.0 in the list before.

Comment: So, you suggest I re-run this command? Do I need to uninstall anything because my situation is different from yours (I can see .Net 4.0 from drop down list to select)?

Comment: Yes try running the command. You don't need to uninstall anything. Note that I was also seeing the .NET 4.0 from the dropdown **before** running the command.

Comment: I have a new idea. I am using Microsoft Expression Encoder SDK 2.0. I think it only supports to run on 32-bit?

Comment: Don't even know what this is :-) If it is an unmanaged library which is 32-bit only you need to [allow execution of 32-bit code in the app pool](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_2TqL1T92L48/S_F1FQAmVeI/AAAAAAAAACQ/bnIay3Cg4HI/s1600/IIS7_Application_Pools_Enable_32-Bit_Applications.png).

Comment: In the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=9A077A3D-58CE-454C-B486-153F0578BE4A&displaylang=en) of this product it says: **Supported Operating Systems:** Windows Vista;Windows XP Service Pack 2. There's no Windows 7.

Comment: Looks like there are some issue to use it with 64-bit Windows. http://social.expression.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/encoder/thread/775b1f04-5b94-41cb-a6fa-c27eace3ee70/

Comment: A new issue, after right clicking the specific application pool for the WCF application, and then select advanced settings, I can not find an item called enable 32-bit application, anything wrong? Should I install anything else to make this option available?

Comment: You have to select the app pool and then Advance Settings... from right hand side action pane. You should see that as Second option in General Category. if not please give the screenshot of the Advance setting you are having